# Themes in SilverStripe

Tags: themes, silverstripe

There is a problem in applying new theme in SilverStripe 3, where only 'simple' theme is working and not any. If I try to set the theme using SilverStripe admin, the theme is dropping down to the basic one and not having any effects of the theme. I couldn't find SSViewer::set_theme() in _config.php to set the theme.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [API docs](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.2/class-SSViewer.html#_set_theme) or [sourcecode](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.2/source-class-SSViewer.html#688-695) you see, that using SSViewer::set_theme() is deprecated.

From SS3.1 on you can set the theme using the [configuration api](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.2/developer_guides/configuration/configuration/) in your */mysite/_config/config.yml*:

```
---
Name: mysite
After:
  - 'framework/*'
  - 'cms/*'
---
# YAML configuration for SilverStripe
# See http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/configuration
# Caution: Indentation through two spaces, not tabs
SSViewer:
  theme: 'mytheme'
```

After changing this in the yml file you'll have to call *?flush* to reset all config caches and get the change working.

Looking at the source code, if you set another theme in "SiteConfig" it should update your config setting, at least for all subclasses of ContentController.

Comment: Just add ?flush to your url, e.g. www.mydomain.com/?flush